# angularjs express get data back via $http post

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, firebase, firebase-admin

I am newbie in firebase admin SDK and trying to get it work on my angularjs app, using and following the steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) and  [this here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data):

I have correctly setup my firebase admin SDK and initialized it like this in `server.js` file on my node server:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com"
});
app.post('/.firebase-user', function (req, res, nex) {
    admin.auth().getUser(req.body.uid)
        .then(function (userRecord) {
            // See the tables below for the contents of userRecord
            console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
        })
             res.status(200).send({data: userRecord.toJSON()});
             return nex();
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
            res.status(117);
            return nex();
        });
});
```

now I want to access `userRecord.toJSON()` inside my controller:

```
$http.post('/.firebase-user', {uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid})
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log($scope.data, response.userRecord);
        });
```

But it is not printing the `userRecord.toJSON()`, instead I get `true undefined` in the console.
Please help me to fetch the info back inside my app. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are a few issues with your (Express) app request handler:

1. In your Angular code, you make a request to the `/.fb` endpoint but in your server code you are listener on the `/.firebase-user` endpoint. I assume you want these to both be the same.
2. Your server code never actually sends a response to the Angular code. I'm surprised your `then()` completion handler ever actually completes. You should need to explicitly send a response with something like `res.status(200).send(userRecord.toJSON())` in the success case and `res.status(400).send({ error: error })` in the error case.
3. You should add a `catch()` to your Angular code to ensure you are catching any errors or failed requests being made by the server code.

Comment: you are right, i forgot to mention the res.send part... and it was a mistake by me not to have the same endpoint, it is fine on my code, but when copied to stackoverflow, i forgot to make it clear. The part that i am missing now is related to the angular catch. could you give an example. thanks.

Comment: Your `response` object has a `data` key, not a `userRecord` key. To see this, do a `console.log(response)` to print out the whole response. In your Angular code, you should use `response.data` instead of `response.userRecord`. That should fix your problem. As for adding a `catch()`, just do something similar to what you did with the `catch()` in your server code.

Comment: i accepted your answer, but i would have appreciated it if you had a nice working example, so that future stackoverflow users could hit on your answer and take it as a model, rather than read through the comments;